# Retrieving Complex Documents from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a set of complex objects from Cloud Firestore.

The data is stored as follows:

[image: database structure]

A book document has authors and translators sub-collections. In order to retrieve the complete list of books there is a call to the database as follows (I have omitted all the other attributes of Book object and kept what is necessary to understand the issue):

```
public void getBooks(final BookRetrievable bookRetrievable) {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    firebaseFirestore.collection("books")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                            Book book = new Book();
                            book.setId(documentSnapshot.getString("id"));
                            book.setName(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
                            book.setStatus(Status.valueOf(documentSnapshot.getString("status")));
                            documentSnapshot.getReference().collection("authors")
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
                                                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                                    Author author = new Author();
                                                    author.setId(documentSnapshot.getString("id"));
                                                    author.setNameInEnglish(documentSnapshot.getString("nameInEnglish"));
                                                    author.setNameInSinhalese(documentSnapshot.getString("nameInSinhalese"));
                                                    author.setWebsite(documentSnapshot.getString("website"));
                                                    authors.add(author);
                                                }

                                                book.setAuthors(authors);

                                                documentSnapshot.getReference().collection("translators")
                                                        .get()
                                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                    ArrayList<Translator> translators = new ArrayList<>();
                                                                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                                                        Translator translator = new Translator();
                                                                        translator.setId(documentSnapshot.getString("id"));
                                                                        translator.setNameInEnglish(documentSnapshot.getString("nameInEnglish"));
                                                                        translator.setNameInSinhalese(documentSnapshot.getString("nameInSinhalese"));
                                                                        translator.setWebsite(documentSnapshot.getString("website"));
                                                                        translators.add(translator);
                                                                    }

                                                                    book.setTranslators(translators);

                                                                    books.add(book);

                                                                    books.sort((Book b1, Book b2) -> b1.getSeriesNo().compareTo(b2.getSeriesNo()));
                                                                    bookRetrievable.onCallback(books);
                                                                } else {
                                                                    bookRetrievable.onCallback(null);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            } else {
                                                bookRetrievable.onCallback(null);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else {
                        bookRetrievable.onCallback(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

However, if I put Logs it seems like there are callbacks as much as the number of Books that are retrieved. Hence is there a way to optimize this code such that there is only one call back per book and one per every author and translator document?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. In order to get all book objects, there is no need to create an object of `Book` class, you can get it from `DocumentSnapshot` object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference booksRef = rootRef.collection("books");
booksRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Book book = document.toObject(Book.class);
                //Do whay you need to do with your Book object
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you need to get the authors and translators of a specific book, then add in your `Book` class two more fileds, `author` and `translator` and the corresponding public getters. To get, let's say the translator from the book object, you can use the following line of code:

```
Translator translator = book.getTranslator();
```

In the same way you can do with the author.

```
Author autothor = book.getAuthor();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It has reduced my code by 200%. My Book Class is as follows:

public class Book {
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private ArrayList<Author> authors;

    private ArrayList<Translator> translators;

}

The getters and setters are already there. From the method you mentioned, I was able to get all the attributes except both Authors and Translators sub-collections. Do I need to make another call to the database to retrieve all of them?

Comment: Good to hear that.  No there is no need to make another call.  You can get them directly from the book object.

Comment: Thanks again.

Now the Book Class has the following:
private Author author;
private ArrayList<Author> authors;
private Translator translator;
private ArrayList<Translator> translators;

as well as their respective getters and setters. However, I am unable to retrieve my Author and Translator data from it.

For example, if you take the sub-collection 'Authors', it has documents like 'author0', 'author1' etc. Will this ensure that all these authors are retrieved in one go?

I am still a bit confused.

Comment: As long as the book object contains the author and translator you can retrieve in a single operation.

Comment: Yes. I think since the Book Class is having subcollections we need to go for another callback to gather all Authors and Translators. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: @CharithaDeSilva In the end with what solution did you go? I am still figuring this out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexMamo Is this something that Firebase detects? How does this work?

Comment: @Rafael I went with the solution provided by Alex and it worked ok!